# Is a set that is an abelian group under addition and a group under multipliation a field?

Tags: group-theory, ring-theory, field-theory, abelian-groups

I suspect the answer to my question is yes, but I'm just checking my understanding. If we have a set which is an Abelian group under addition and a group under multiplication is it then defined as a field?

Cheers Matt

Comment: $\{0\}$ is a such a structure, but is not a field.

Comment: why not? aren't you concerned that The Trustees Of The Empty Set will be pursuing you for damages if you persist?

Comment: Ahh, interesting point. Many thanks, all this sort of stuff massively improves my understanding.

Comment: Did you read the definition of a field before asking?

Comment: Distributivity is the most critically important thing to think about here.  Without it, there need be _no relationship whatsoever_ between addition and multiplication.  For example, they could be equal!

Answer (score 2):

In general, no, because the distributive laws may not hold.

With that and a minor modification, yes. The multiplicative group has to leave out $0$, because $0$ won't be invertible.

So if you have a ring (with identity) such that the nonzero elements are an abelian group, then yes, you have a field.

If the nonzero elements are just a *group* then you have a division ring.

Comment: Don't we also need the distributivity?

Comment: @StefanHamcke I don't know about you dudes but I rarely post something I don't edit in the next few minutes. You guys didn't even give me 40 seconds to reread everything and polish! :0

Comment: I couldn't resist, sorry :-) I will heed your advice.

Comment: @StefanHamcke Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Take for example $(\Bbb Z_4,+,0,-)$ which is an Abelian group. On $\{1,2,3\}=\Bbb Z_4-\{0\}$ define $a*b=((a-1)+(b-1)\bmod 3)+1$ (so that this set becomes $\Bbb Z_3$). But it fails to be a field as $2*2=3$ but $2*(1+1)$ had to give $2*1+2*1=2+2=0$. That means that $*$ does not distribute over $+$, so it is not a field.

More generally, there cannot be a field where you have to add $1$ to itself at least $4$ times before you get $0$ as the sum, since the characteristic $p$, the minimal number such that $\underbrace{1+1+\cdots+1}_{p\text{ times}}=0$, must always be a prime.

On the other hand there is a unique field with $4$ elements, the factor ring $\Bbb Z_2[X]/\langle X^2+X+1\rangle$. It's additive group is the Klein four-group and its multiplicative group is $\Bbb Z_3=\langle X\rangle$